# View browser usage by location in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to separate out browser usage by location in Google Analytics?  Like for example, seeing that all traffic from Nevada came from what browsers?  Or, selecting a single browser and seeing where all of the traffic came from that used that browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the default reporting page for the property you would like to review:

1. Go to the Audience tab in the left menu bar and select "Demographics" then "Location"
2. Select "Technology" then "Browser" from the "Secondary Dimension" menu (just above the data table)
3. Switch between geographic divisions (Country/Territory, City, Continent, Sub Continent Region), click through linked regions in the data table, and/or use the search box to drill down to the locations you'd like to review

Answer (score 2):

Log in to Analytics Account Dashboard.

Click on Select Account and Select an Account. On the Top row of Report, there is option 
for Custom Reporting.

You can choose as many as parameters and variables which are guided by Google. Go and Create whatever you want.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question at all.

Comment: then what do you expect?